# What the meaning of the bolded text in the following context?

Tags: meaning, word-in-context

**One closes** Berger's book newly conscious of the significance of smart questions - but also vaguely uncertain about how exactly to cultivate them in service to worthy change. Some questions are harder than others.

What's meaning of 'closes' here?

Comment: What it says - to shut the book, with the implication that one has just finished reading it.

Comment: Didn't get it...

Comment: @Sam it would help if you explained more what is confusing you.  [*One*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_(pronoun)) is a personal pronoun, like *you*, that means "any person".  So it basically means "When a person shuts this book after reading it..."

Comment: One can easily understand it. After one closes the book, one is presumed to have read it.